# redirecting http://domain.com to htttp://www.domain.com in IIS

Tags: iis, redirect, web

my site currently isn't working if I only type `http://domain.com` in the browser instead of `www.domain.com`. I was thinking about redirecting the domain.com to `www.domain.com` in `IIS` but somehow it isn't working correctly.

I get this error message in the browser:

```
Hostname lookup for "domain name" failed
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

create a new web site for the subdomain using the IIS Manager, and add the www sub-domain (e.g. www.domain.com) as a new host header value listening to the same IP address as specified in the DNS entry. The port is set to 80 (the default for http requests). The host header can be added by clicking on the advanced tab next to the IP address configuration for that web site application. 
Set the home directory for the www subdomain web site to the same directory. For example, if the domain.com points to C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\ and the www subdomain needs to be setup for C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\

There are some chances you need to configure your dns too.
this depends on how your dns provider is, please their help site or support.

Comment: IIS was unable to start the site. Another site may already be using the port you configured for this site. Please select an unused port for this site... is the error message I get once i try to run the new website (subdomain)